# how to detect moment when mapped network drives are lost on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, mappeddrive

For some reason, I keep losing access to my company's network drives.  I'm using Windows 7.  What could cause this?  I'm the only one that VPN's to a certain client using the Windows 7 VPN functionality, but I haven't confirmed this.  Is there something I could implement that tells me the moment that I lose access, so I can easily determine the cause (perhaps with a windows service)?  This isn't my question, but I'll give extra bonus points if you can tell me the cause.  :-)

**Error Message if VPN'ed too long:**

[image]

**I always have to fix them by doing the following:**

```
net use u: /delete
net use u: \\company.local\dfsroot\users\myusername
```

**Screen Shots for VPN setup:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're losing them completely, or they are temporarily disconnected? Win7 I believe has a timeout that will disconnect unused shares (puts an X on My Computer) but reconnects when you try to use the share again.

If you're mapping over the VPN, it could be that your VPN isn't forwarding certain packets needed to keep the connection alive, or it could be a configuration issue depending on how you're doing it (such as suggested off http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbusinessserver/thread/22358ba5-eba3-4a34-a935-bb18a92a8dbe )

You might want to elaborate more on how you're configured; we know the client is Win7, but what is the server running, and what kind of VPN configuration do you have? And is the issue permanent, or does your fix still fail after awhile? Is there anything in the logs? How is your connectivity to the server? Is the connection reliable? Are there logs on the VPN server? Information on these items can help narrow down the issue.

Comment: +1 for VPN connectivity and the timeout suggestion. If you connect via a wireless signal and your connection gets dropped (even for a short moment) it can cause this problem with network drives.

Comment: @Bart - I can still see the drives listed, but when I click on the mapped drive, I get the error (just posted image in my question).  So I guess permanently until I remap it with the commands above my error image.  I'll put together some details on how it's mapped tomorrow

Comment: won't be able to reproduce as I work for a new organization now.  Marking as answer unless someone has a better answer.  I just rebooted my machine when this occurred.  Never did find the cause.