# Transferring 60GB of data over fiber connection - VPN connection times out

Tags: vpn, sql-server-2008, timeout, file-transfer

In an attempt to transfer a 60GB file (SQL database file) over the wire via a VPN connection, we're only able to get about 1/8 the file over.  How can we get around this timeout issue?  Or do we have ways to break apart the file into multiple pieces?

Just looking for ideas.

Comment: Split it MacGyver. You have a knife and duct tape.

Comment: There are dozens of ways to split a file into smaller chunks for transmission. The one I like to use is a multi-file RAR. However, perhaps you should find out why your VPN is dropping your connection...

Comment: @mailq haha!  I don't usually bring my knife to work.  They have policies.

Comment: How are you transferring the data?

Comment: just a Windows transfer using Windows' VPN.  Configuration of VPN in my link in Holocryptic's answer comment I made.  I haven't yet tried FTP.

Comment: Your better off using robocopy to make the transfer as it can recover from a timeout.  FTP is another option as you said.

Comment: I suggest you figure out why your VPN is being shite. It shouldn't time out because it's one big fat chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [WinRar](http://www.win-rar.com/download.html) have the ability to break up files into smaller chunks that can be re-assembled later.  But like Mark mentions, you may want to look at why your VPN is dropping the line.

Comment: here's how we set up the VPN in Windows Server 2008 (same in Windows 7) if you have any ideas.  For now, I'll attempt to use WIN-RAR.
http://serverfault.com/questions/294263/how-to-detect-moment-when-mapped-network-drives-are-lost-on-windows-7

Comment: so that split up the file fine, but the VPN still closes when I tried transferring volumes larger than 4GB.  That would take me merely 15 days to transfer.  Is there a faster way to transfer files over the web than a Windows transfer?  I cannot use bittorrents as this database has donor data from 11,000 collection sites.